# Getting objects from json data tree, issue with reusing function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote a code (with help from another question) in order to get objects from a json tree.

```
let objFound = null;
 
function getObjFromValue(obj, prop, val) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        if (objFound == null) {
            if (key === prop && val === obj[key]) {
                objFound = obj;
            }
 
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                getObjFromValue(obj[key], prop, val);
            }
        }
    });
 
    return objFound;
}
```

The problem with it is, that I can use it only once since the variable `objFound`  is global (I need it to stop the forEach loop somehow) and never gets nulled again, so when I make another search I receive the previous and first object that the function found. Is there a way to improve/fix my function?

Comment: just move `let objFound = null` inside the function before your forEach, and make your recursive call assign to it. `if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') { objFound = getObjFromValue(obj[key], prop, val); }`. But if you refactor to use a `for` loop you can `break` as soon as you find a match instead of having to let the whole `forEach` run.

Comment: I've tried to refactor it to use a for loop but its not working for me: https://pastebin.com/12w2GUUf . What is working is to add a line at the start of the function to check if the found object from before is the same or different from what the current search is searching for `if (objFound != null && objFound[prop] != val) objFound = null;`. By the way, your answer also works. Can I ask you why? Because I understand that the typeof object function keeps executing everytime it finds an array.

Comment: The reason my initial comment works is because there is a top level null check that avoids any further assignment to `foundObject` after the first match, even though the `forEach` has to keep running. In your refactor there isn't this check so you need to add one after the recursive call returns. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fg86jzrs/) of your pastebin code which works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local variable to return the value, after setting the global variable to null.

```js
let toReturn = objFound;
objFound = null;
return toReturn;
```

However, this global variable approach might not be the best one. The comment of @pilchard has a good alternative, making the variable local.

Comment: Indeed @pilchard's answer is a good alternative. This is also a good one. My code can be fixed with `if (objFound != null && objFound[prop] != val) objFound = null;` at the start of the function. Thank you for your answer!